# Customize a Spinner to look like a button

Tags: android, button, spinner

I've got a custom button defined as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary" android:endColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I'd like to create a spinner which, when not clicked looks like the button, and only when pressed showing the selectable items. The default spinner is not very pretty, and does not fit my design.

Anybody knows how to acheive this?

Comment: I have another approach for spinner. You can replace spinner by Popup Menu, here is basic guideline https://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example also you can watch video on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXUDqGaToe0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                            <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner_start_day_def"
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:minWidth="70dp"
                            android:popupBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textAlignment="center" />
```

That was easy, android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"